# On-demand self-hosted AWS EC2 runner for GitHub Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, github-actions

```
name: On-demand self-hosted AWS EC2 runner for GitHub Actions
uses: machulav/ec2-github-runner@v2
with:

   github-token: *** 
   ec2-instance-type: t2.micro
   ec2-instance-id: i-03d221ab975187b
```

*Error: Error: The 'mode' input is not specified
Error: The 'mode' input is not specified
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mode' of undefined
Error: Cannot read property 'mode' of undefined*

Can anybody give how to mention **mode** in this with the start/stop operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- start - to start a new runner;
- stop - to stop the previously created runner.

Start mode is that you want to start a new runner even tho your precious build is still running.
Stop mode means you want to stop the previous run and start a new one.

```
github-token: *** 
ec2-instance-type: t2.micro
ec2-instance-id: i-03d221ab975187b
mode: start
```